# ComponentOne Report - Changing Forecolor

Tags: c#, wpf, componentone

I am using C1Report and I want to change the forecolor of my output, but I cannot. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with my code? Why can I not change the forecolor?

```
string script = "Detail.ForeColor =rgb(80,80,80)";
rpt.Sections.Detail.OnFormat = script;
c1DocumentViewer1.Document = rpt.FixedDocumentSequence;
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional tag @Sir Grant Winney

Answer (score 3):

The Detail section of C1Report does not have a ForeColor property. You may try setting its BackColor property or you may set the [ForeColor](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1report/index.html#!XMLDocuments/C1R/html/P_C1_C1Report_Field_ForeColor.htm) property of the fields present in the Detail Section.